# Which filter should be used when i want to add watermark to a video?

Tags: ffmpeg

Hi everyone,

I want to add a watermark to a video use a picture.
here is the problem [image]

and this is my command:

`c:\ffmpeg.exe -y -i c:\ffmpeg\input\walk.mp4 -acodec copy -b 300k -vf "movie=w1.jpg [watermark];[in][watermark] overlay=5:5  [out]" c:\ffmpeg\output\walk.mp4`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you command should work just fine. it's you're ffmpeg version which is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `overlay` filter, but first you need to use a recent build because the version you are using is considered to be absolutely ancient due to how active the FFmpeg project is. You can get builds for Windows at [Zeranoe FFmpeg builds](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/).

Now that you are not using a graybeard ffmpeg here is the most basic example:

```
ffmpeg -i background.avi -i watermark.jpg -filter_complex overlay output.mp4
```

The [`overlay` filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay-1) will show how to position the watermark. This example will place the watermark 10 pixels from the bottom right corner of the main video and copy your audio as in your example:

```
ffmpeg -i background.avi -i watermark.jpg -filter_complex overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10 -codec:a copy output.mp4
```